# How to correctly initialize a window in classic Titanium?

Tags: javascript, titanium

I'm trying to define a new window for use inside a Classic Titanium application for iOS. For the window to work properly, some preprocessing is required. This preprocessing includes the creation of the UI components -- such as labels, tables, and buttons --, the assembling of this components, and the addition of event listeners. However, I don't think **this** is the *best* way to do it. Any insight?

```
function LandingPage() {
    this.prepareForExecution();
}

LandingPage.prototype = {
    constructor: LandingPage,

    _proxy: Ti.UI.createWindow({
        title: "To Do List",
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
        navBarHidden: false,
        orientationModes: [
            Ti.UI.PORTRAIT,
            Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT,
            Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT
        ]
    }),

    get proxy() {
        return this._proxy;
    },

    prepareForExecution: function () {
        this.createUIcomponents();
        this.buildUserInterface();
        this.addEventListeners();
        this.populateTaskTable();
    },

    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Alloy I would use a CommonJS module for each window with code like:

```
module.exports = function Controller() {
  var $ = this;

  // if you need views accessable assign them to $
  $.index = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title: "To Do List",
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    navBarHidden: false,
    orientationModes: [
      Ti.UI.PORTRAIT,
      Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT,
      Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT
    ]
  });

  // do whatever pre-processing you need

  // interface to get a specific or main view
  $.getView = function getView(id) {
    return $[id || 'index'];
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to make use of the module pattern and titanium exports for this.

Here's an example from a recent project:

**Views.js**

```
var HubWindow = (function () {
    var homeWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        height: deviceHeight,
        width: deviceWidth,
        layout:'vertical',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
    });

    var addView = function(){
        for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
            homeWindow.add(arguments[i]);
        }
    };

    var openWindow = function(){
        homeWindow.open();
    };

    return{
        add: addView,
        open: openWindow
    };
})();

exports.HubWindow = HubWindow;
```

**App.js**

```
var App = (function(){
    var Views = require('views');

    var launch = function(){
        Views.HubWindow.open();
        ...
    };

    return {
        launch: launch
    }
})();

App.launch();
```

I save prototypes for views that are are going to be created programmatically.